# A decoding error occurred when I called Graphviz using Python

Tags: python, graphviz

Here's my code：

```
from graphviz import Digraph
ps = Digraph(name='pet-shop', node_attr={'shape': 'plaintext'},format='png')
ps.node('parrot')
ps.node('dead')
ps.edge('parrot', 'dead')
ps.view()
```

Here is the error message：

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):**
  File "D:/code/pythonProject/pythonProject10/1.py", line 6, in <module>
    ps.view()
  File "C:\Users\MaLu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MaLu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\graphviz\rendering.py", line 185, in view
    return self.render(filename=filename, directory=directory, view=True,
  File "C:\Users\MaLu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MaLu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\graphviz\rendering.py", line 122, in render
    rendered = self._render(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MaLu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MaLu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend\execute.py", line 88, in run_check
    _write_stderr(proc.stderr)
  File "C:\Users\MaLu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend\execute.py", line 114, in _write_stderr
    stderr = stderr.decode(stderr_encoding)
***UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 6: invalid start byte***
```

I tried to reconfigure the environment variables，But it doesn't work.How do I solve this problem？

Comment: Which version of GraphViz are you using (type `dot -v` at command-line) ? Which version of pyGraphviz (type `pip show graphviz`) ? Please include those version outputs in your question.

Comment: I suppose from the stacktrace (`execute.py, line 88`) that the python-wrapper can't find your required Graphviz tool. Did you install it like explained in the User Guide: [`Installation`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#installation) ?

Comment: And please tell us, which environment-variables you reconfigured (maybe also your intend when doing) - all this may help to figure out the broken connection between your python-code and the required `dot` command-line tool.

Comment: This is the version of Graphviz I used：dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)</br>:This is the version of pyGraphviz I used :Version: 0.20.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like rendering/viewing the PNG output fails.

#### Try alternative formats

You could try to store the graph rendered in a different [format](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#formats) setting the `format` property and then using the `render()` method.

For example SVG or default PDF.

```
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(name='pet-shop', node_attr={'shape': 'plaintext'})  # choose format later
dot.node('parrot')
dot.node('dead')
dot.edge('parrot', 'dead')

# debug print the graph's source to console
print(dot.source)

# try to save the rendered graph as SVG, so you can open it externally
dot.format = 'svg'
dot.render(directory='.').replace('\\', '/')
# see file in current directory 'pet-shop.gv.svg'

# when the viewing fails, it means either rendering to SVG or viewing fails
dot.view()
```

Now open the rendered and saved SVG file using your system's viewer, e.g. a browser.

You can additionally try rendering and saving as PNG or, as a last resort, use the default PDF format:

```
# try to save the rendered graph as PNG, so you can open it externally
dot.format = 'png'
dot.render(directory='.').replace('\\', '/')
# see file in current directory 'pet-shop.gv.png'

# when the viewing fails, it means either rendering to PNG or viewing fails
dot.view()
```

#### Pipe the output to the console

When using [`pipe()`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#piped-output) to debug-print the output, you can add it to your question so we can help you to find any rendering issue or warn for viewer problems that may come up within your environment.

```
# for binary formats like PNG just print the raw bytes
print(dot.pipe())

# for textual formats like SVG we need some UTF-8 encoding
print(dot.pipe(encoding='utf-8'))
```